# Unable to Add Dictionary<string, string> to List<Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I hit a null reference exception when attempting to add a `Dictionary<string,string>` to a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` variable. I'm unable to find the cause.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> ID_Name_List { get; set; }
}

MyObject obj1 = new MyObject();

Dictionary<string, string> ID_Name_Pair = new Dictionary<string, string>();

ID_Name_Pair.Add("1", "Jane");

List<Dictionary<string, string>> ID_Name_List_2 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>(); //For Testing

ID_Name_List_2.Add(ID_Name_Pair); //SUCCESS

obj1.ID_Name_List.Add(ID_Name_Pair); //ERROR - System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

My `obj1.ID_Name_List` variable has the same `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` type with `ID_Name_List_2`

Why did my `obj1.ID_Name_List` hit an error while `ID_Name_List_2` is successful?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Whee do you assign a value to `ID_Name_List`?
Try `public List<Dictionary<string, string>> ID_Name_List { get; } = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();` or assign a value in the constructor of `MyObject`.

Comment: Nope, I used it directly from the object to add the dictionary value. Am I missing an action?

Comment: You forgot to init ID_Name_List ... obj1.ID_Name_List = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Comment: Null reference is not about type mismatch, it's just null there, you never call new on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize `ID_Name_List`.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> ID_Name_List { get; set; }

    public MyObject()
    {
        ID_Name_List = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Geez! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

of course you ran into a NullReferenceException. Your `obj1.obj1.ID_Name_List` (object) is not initialized.

try this

```
obj1.ID_Name_List = new List<Dictionary<string, string>();
obj1.ID_Name_List.Add(ID_Name_Pair); // will work like a charm;
```

alternatively,

```
public class MyObject
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> ID_Name_List { get; set; }
    public MyObject() {
         ID_Name_List = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }
}
```